# Why did upgrading Ubuntu from 18.04 to 20.04.4 break emacs?

Tags: upgrade, windows-subsystem-for-linux, emacs

I just updated my ubuntu to 20.04.4 and noticed that emacs is no longer there. Other programs that I had downloaded prior to updating, like racket and ocaml, still work. Emacs however, is not working - the emacs command is not recognized. I see that I still have a /etc/emacs folder (`$ whereis emacs` told me that), so I am not sure why the command `$ emacs` is not recognized anymore.

I would be interested in knowing both how to fix this but also what caused it. I am using WSL2, if that is relevant.

Edit: if it is relevant, I have discovered that npm (which I installed with apt) and angular (which I installed with npm) are also claiming to be not installed (eg `Command 'npm' not found, but can be installed with:`). When I run `$ whereis npm` the response is `npm:`   . When I run `whereis ng`, the response is `ng: /usr/bin/ng`.

Edit 2: I have corrected my post to say I was using 18.04, not 18. My mistake, I apologize. I did not know core 18 existed.

Edit 3: `apt update` is failing, and I think it is related to the way the update removed node.
[image]

Comment: How exactly did you update WSL2? Also, does `/usr/bin/env emacs` work to launch emacs? You can [edit] your question to add this. Thanks!

Comment: You've provided no specifics as to how you installed `emacs`.. eg. if you installed the *snap* package of `emacs` then no change at all occurred in migrating a system from 18.04 to 20.04; however with *deb* packages they'll need to be upgraded along with an upgrade of 18.04 to 20.04... ie. answers will vary on details you've not provided..   I'd also check you $PATH for issues you may have introduced in error.

Comment: @cocomac I didn't update WSL2 itself, I just updated Ubuntu using the `do-release-upgrade` command. The command you suggested generated the following response: `/usr/bin/env: ‘emacs’: No such file or directory`. Do you mean to say I should move this comment to my post?

Comment: @guiverc I am sorry, unfortunately I do not remember how I installed emacs. I am very sorry about that. What should I check my path for? And with deb packages, when you say they need to upgraded, how would I do that? Is that something done with `apt update && apt upgrade`?

Comment: @guiverc I'd be relatively confident that the OP actually meant 18.04 (a common mistake for new contributors, it seems), since that's what would typically be running under WSL.  Also, snap doesn't run without a lot of extra work in WSL, but I can't rule it out entirely.

Comment: @manissss Is there any chance you had tried to enable Systemd via something like WSL2Hacks or Genie?

Comment: @NotTheDr01ds you are right. I apologize @guiverc. I was using 18.04, my mistake. For deb packages then, should I purge the old version (eg the `/etc/emacs` files) and reinstall the package?

Comment: @NotTheDr01ds I do not know what Systemd, WSL2Hacks, or Genie are. Is there a way for me to check this?

Comment: @manissss Hmm.  I know you don't recall how you installed Emacs, but if there's a chance that you installed via Snap, then that would have required that you had enabled Systemd in WSL in order to do that.  Otherwise you probably installed via `apt`.  Let's try a different approach, though - Run `grep -i emacs /var/log/apt/history.log` and add the results to the question.  Thanks!

Comment: @NotTheDr01ds for some reason, Stack Exchange won't let me edit my post due to the "volume of spam and abuse originating from [my] network." I have no idea what is happening there. Anyways, is there anyway I can show you the output?

Comment: See if this works https://drive.google.com/file/d/19blRWNq2yG2-X_8krvJyIlluS4ZSscpP/view?usp=sharing.

Comment: A few new discoveries. First, the emacs folder I mentioned in my post is actually empty: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1y_N_I8MlCGSVkF2f6jJmKuYmcpm5xZu-/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Second, it looks like, during the update process, some of my programs were explicitly uninstalled. I would still like to no know how or why since I know that I didn't do this explicitly. https://drive.google.com/file/d/18nKFgIP7kEFM4qIWol6u6jWBZXrJFlwh/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Is it possible that emacs and node were uninstalled because their python dependency was uninstalled? During the update process, python3 was uninstalled and a newer version of python3 was installed. If emacs and node depended on that old version of python3, would they have been uninstalled?